# How to go back to previous indentation level in insert mode?

Tags: vim

Sometimes vim's smartindent does not pick the correct level of indentation for the next line once you hit enter and you'd like to go back to the indentation level of the previous line and just go from there. I know that you can hit `ctrl-d` a few times to achieve this but it would be more useful for a key that immediately goes to the indentation level of the line above.

Comment: You should drop `smartindent` there's probably a better default `indentexpr` for your file type.

Comment: I don't actually use smartindent and use the filetype's plugin indentation rules as you've suggested. They're not completely accurate however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't be bothered to install a plugin for such a simple task (I couldn't), try this simple mapping:

```
:inoremap <C-D> <Esc>:call setline(".",substitute(getline(line(".")),'^\s*',matchstr(getline(line(".")-1),'^\s*'),''))<CR>I
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in insert mode will do the deed: indent the current line like the previous line.

This works best before you start typing on the new line, because it will reset the cursor to just past the indentation.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most direct and easiest answer. I've actually went with the plugin that Ingo posted however.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's pure coincidence, but Alexey Radev has just published the [prev_indent plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4575), which provides an insert mode mapping and `:PrevIndent` command to move the current line to the previous indentation level.

Answer (score 1):

In normal mode you can use `<` and `>` to increase or decrease indentation. They work as expected with movements, visual selection and `>>` `<<` for the current line. You can also use `=` to chose the "correct" indentation level, again it works as expected with regards to movements etc.

So what I usually do is fix indentation errors in normal mode after I'm done editing, by a combination of block selecting and using `=`, and then fixing individual lines with `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: `=` does nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<C-O>=G` to indent from cursor to end of file in insert mode. Or `<C-O><<` to remove one indentation level.

Comment: Ctrl+d and ctrl+t are easier to use while in insert mode.